# Reading mixed type binary data with Numpy (characters, floats and integers)

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to read binary files with mixed types  (of varying data structures) into NumPy arrays.

The data is organized in a *.dat file and a *.dict (plain text that contains the data dictionary). An example of the data dictionary I have is the following:

"Name"           "s"    "50"
"Project ID"     "i"    "4"
"amount"         "f"    "8"

My idea then is to have a class that I'd instantiate and load with data by just calling

```
f = data_bin()
f.load("profit.bin")
```

This code is working flawlessly whenever I have a mix of integers and floats, but as soon as I throw a string field in the middle, it throws me the error
.
 "TypeError: float argument required, not numpy.string_"

The class I wrote is bellow.
As a side note, I can say that the I really need the data in Numpy (for performance and compatibility with existing code reasons), but I can live with going to something like python lists and from there to Numpy.

I appreciate any help with this!

```
class data_bin:
  def __init__(self):
    self.datafile="No file loaded yet"
    self.dictfile="No file loaded yet"
    self.dictionary=None
    self.data=None

  def load(self, file):
    self.datafile = file
    self.dictfile=file[0:len(file)-3]+"dict"
    self.builds_dt()
    self.loads_data()

  def builds_dt(self):
    w=open(self.dictfile,'rb')
    w.readline()
    w.readline()
    q=w.readline()
    dt=[]
    while len(q)>0:
        a=q.rstrip().split(',')
        field_name=a[0]
        field_type=a[1]
        field_length=a[2]
        dt.append((field_name,field_type+field_length))
        q=w.readline()
    self.dictionary=dt

  def loads_data(self):
    f=open(self.datafile,'rb')
    self.data=np.fromfile(f, dtype=self.dictionary)

  def info(self):
    print "Binnary Source: ", self.datafile
    print "   Data Types:", self.dictionary
    try:
      print "   Number of records: ", self.data.shape[0]
    except:
      print "   No valid data loaded"
```

Comment: You can't mix datatypes in one numpy array. it clashes fundamentally for how a numpy array is defined. Pandas might work though, or possibly structured arrays.

Comment: @M4rtini, My idea was to use structured arrays, and I actually thought that Numpy was loading the data in a structured (aka record array), whioch I though would allow me to have strings (since it allows me to have different data types like integers and floats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to store all of your data in a numpy array by row, you can. For example:

```
myArr = np.array([1, 2.5, 'hello', {'a':7}], dtype='O')
--> array([1, 2.5, 'hello', {'a': 7}], dtype=object)
```

This will create a numpy array of objects. Since everything in Python is an object, it works. Unfortunately, you lose a lot of reason for having a numpy array in the first place. If you need to perform calculations on the data, I would suggest separating them by data type and working from there (e.g., parse based on the 2nd column, or use an np.where combined with np.take and a recarray from np.loadtxt). Otherwise, I would suggest sticking to python lists or something similar.

Having said that, a number of functions still work:

```
e.g., 
myArr = np.append(myArr, ('what?', 5.2))
--> array([1, 2.5, 'hello', {'a': 7}, 'what?', '5.2'], dtype=object)

myArr.reshape(2,3)
--> array([[1, 2.5, 'hello'],
           [{'a': 7}, 'what?', '5.2']], dtype=object)
```

If I've missed something regarding what you're going for, let me know.

Comment: I do need to perform computations, thus the need to use Numpy, and the idea is to read the database, perform computations (and modify it) and write it back in a binary that will have strings, floats and integers.  What do you think would be the best approach for that?

Comment: It turns out that the code works, and as suggested by @M4rtini, what Numpy creates is a record array (or structured array).